# Which test should I use to test this hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, likert

I am bit new to research data analysis and SPSS software.

So I am bit confused if I am doing it in right way.

Survey(with companies)

My company believes that xyz with help in doing abc action   1  2  3  4 5(likert)

Hypothesis
H0= companies do not believe that xyz with help in doing abc action

H1= companies do believe that xyz with help in doing abc action

Now which test can I use to test the hypothesis?
(or should i just use mean?)

I have not measured or do not have data either the abc action actually happened for each case or not.

Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain your likert scale more please? Does 4 represent xyz is neutral/useless for abc and 7 represents most useful whereas 1 is actively harmful? In this case, put your H0 in 4 do a two sided test (t-test or non parametric as suggested in the answer) and you're fine. If 1 means neutral and you only gave them options to answer that it helps or is neutral, it is much more debatable if 1 on the scale remains an acceptable H0 choice and by extension if your questionnaire is acceptable.

Comment: Also, did you insist that the distance between any two adjacent options on your likert scale is the same as the distance between any two other adjacent options? The best way to do this is to put just the numbers on them and not descriptive text labels (Is "moderate" really as far from "not much" as it is from "a good amount"?) If you weren't careful here, you cannot do t-tests.

Comment: thank you. ok if my likert is 1-5 with 3 as neutral(edited), so now do you mean that i can carry out t test with 3 as test value(check if it different than neutral value) and decide for hypothesis checking if it is significant?

Comment: If you also made it clear that the distances between the options are equally long (by putting numbers on the options) you are good to go. Jeffrey explained which tests you can use (one sample t-test with respect to H_0 in 3 if your sample size is >30 otherwise wilcoxon signed rank test).

Comment: can you please provide me reference to paper or may be example. thank you or may be paper or thesis using it. thank you.

Comment: t-tests on likert scales have been done thousands of times. do you want just an example to see how to do it or rather a methodological paper that explains why it is an acceptable procedure under some conditions?

Comment: oh ok i was thinking that the Jeffrey was some writer.lol.oh ok respondent below. I was trying to get reference where people uses that 3 as test value to test hypothesis using mean.Thanks

Comment: just take the neutral position as null hypothesis and any effect positive or negative needs to be proven. when 3 is neutral out of 5, 3 it is.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. It sounds like you are interested in the mean belief value of all possible/relevant companies (this is called the population parameter) and are estimating it by asking a subset of those companies what their beliefs are (this is called the sample statistic).

There are several statistical approaches you can use to determine if your sample mean is significantly different from some value (e.g., 1 or the midpoint of the scale). You could use a one-sample location t-test which will assume that the distribution of belief ratings is roughly "normal" (i.e., shaped like a bell-curve). You could also use the one-sample Wilcoxin signed-rank test which will do the same but without making that assumption. Both approaches are available in SPSS.

Another thing to consider would be how many belief ratings you get per company. The aforementioned approaches would work well if you have one per company but not if you ask multiple employees per company. In this case, you would need a more sophisticated approach (e.g., multilevel modeling) to account for the fact that ratings from employees at the same company are not statistically independent.

Comment: Thank you. I get only one case from each company. Let's suppose I have 100 data and sample mean is 6. Then I should be able to say "majority of the companies belive that xyz will help doing abc actiion" right?
but same thing I want to assert as hypothesis after getting the mean, how do i do that. If there were score either abc action did happened or not may be I would have been able to run some test but since i don't have that, any ways to run the test or test the hypothesis? thanks

Comment: You need some "test value" to compare the mean to. This would allow you to say that your sample mean was significantly different from (e.g., greater than) that value. So what value would you consider to mean that the company did not have a meaningful amount of trust in xyz? A mean of 1 would be the lowest possible, but perhaps you want to know if your sample mean is different from some other value such as the midpoint of 4. You would go to Analyze > Compare Means > One-Sample T-Test, select your variable as the test variable, and enter your desired test value.